# Is there a way to append a map to a slice?

Tags: go, slice

I'm making a new programming language in Golang. For my lexer, I want to append my token maps to my slice.
For example:

```golang
var tokens []map[string]string
tokens = append(tokens, {"type": "number", "value": "123"})
```

I keep getting this error though: `syntax error: unexpected {, expecting expression`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For it to be a valid expression, you need to specify the type for the literal:

```
tokens = append(tokens, map[string]string{"type": "number", "value": "123"})
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I'm new to go. I tought it to myself 2 weeks ago and know I want to put my knowledge to the test.

Comment: @Lukas my apologies, I didn't even know it does that.

Comment: @mkopriva: yup, [15 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer). We end up missing an entire side of SO by not asking questions.